# When is it considered good design to directly set property values on an object without the use of a setter?

Tags: oop, class, setter, getter, getter-setter

This may not be the best kind of question suited to stackoverflow, but I'm only after an answer that best describes **why** programmers sometimes don't use setters/getters for properties, e.g. in the case of property injection (DI).

Consider this example...

```
class Test
{
    public propertyA;
    protected propertyB;

    public function setPropertyB(val)
    {
        // do some logic to validate 'val'
        this.propertyB = val;
    }

    public function getPropertyB()
    {
        return this.propertyB;
    }
}
```

Why would you choose the style of directly setting `propertyA`:

```
var Test = new Test();
Test.propertyA = 1;
```

Over the setter option for `propertyB`:

```
var Test = new Test();
Test.setPropertyB(1);
```

I always use the setter/getter approach, but I have seen some pretty established frameworks using the `propertyA` approach interspersed with the `propertyB` approach. What benefits do we have using this method?

Comment: Such question may also suit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you might not care about encapsulation:

1. You might be throwing away the project 15 minutes later.
2. You might have found getters/setters to be bottlenecks for your CPU-bound code, causing you to optimize for performance instead of design.
3. The instance field might be immutable and read-only, so there might be no danger in exposing it.
4. You're too lazy to write getters/setters.

Answer (score 2):

You should use getters and setters because they allow you to control the interface to your objects.

For example, let's say I have a bank account class in a Java application:

```
class BankAccount {
    private int balance;

    BankAccount() {
        balance = 0;
    }

    public void deposit(int amount) {
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(int amount) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
}
```

When my software needs to alter a bank account's balance through deposits and withdrawals, it calls the appropriate methods.

Now, along comes some sneaky individual who manages to figure out that they can increase their bank balance by telling their internet banking software to withdraw negative amounts of money. I can fix this bug by adding a precondition to the withdraw method, and the bug goes away.

If the balance field was instead public, and a whole bunch of classes were just manipulating it's value arbitrarily, those classes would now need to be changed. If some of those external classes were written by third parties, then we're looking at a whole lot of pain to get the bug fixed.

Why would you use public fields? In the general case, you probably shouldn't. Some languages allow you to have a field scoped as public, then if you need to add a getter/setter later on you can do so without changing your object's interface (I believe C# does this, but correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: yeah 100% agree with the reasons for using setters/getters, it's something that has always puzzled me as to why people **wouldn't** use them (I've seen examples from pretty competent programmers - although I can't think of any off the top of my head). It's because of that which makes me wonder whether there are any major benefits (especially when dealing with insensitive properties) to not using the setters